# C# skills - which will be easier, IOS or Android development?

Tags: c#, android, ios5

I'd like to diversify my skills into the tablet and smartphone arena. I have 5+ years experince in C#, asp.net and ajax. 
Which platform will be an easier to learn to develop on next: Android or IOS?

Comment: This is actually off topic here..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Coming from a Java background and having developed on both Android and iOS, I can definitely say that Android is a much easier leap to make. Java & C# are very similar, so you'll mainly be confronted with minor language differences and learning the Android API. Objective C on the other hand is a very different beast and can be as finicky as C++ at times. It's a great language, but the learning curve is much higher.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that if you know well c# and .NEt you can use this skills also for developing in android and iOS with mono.

For iOS [monoTouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch) and for android [mono for android](http://android.xamarin.com/) .

Answer (score 2):

Consider the development for Windows Phone: I suppose there are more facilities to find your's niche as a single developer because the platform is young.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you have enough experience to be past the point where language familiarity matters little. You will probably be equally comfortable and equally annoyed by both. Android promotes Java and Eclipse, which are both consistently annoying across all platforms. Apple promotes Objective-C and Xcode, [which are [great on [the Mac platform]], [except for [the annoying bracket soup]]. Pick your poison according to taste.